# Do AppDomains execute in their own threads ?

Tags: c#, multithreading, appdomain

If I run this code, will each `AppDomain` execute in a different thread?

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
 {
     /// Create AppDomain and run code
 });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AppDomains do not get their own thread per default. You may execute code in another AppDomain using existing threads or call a method in the AppDomain, that creates new thread(s). In fact, unless you specifically creates additional threads calling code in another domain will execute on the process' main thread.

From the [AppDomain documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain(VS.100).aspx)

> Multiple application domains can run
>   in a single process; however, there is
>   not a one-to-one correlation between
>   application domains and threads.
>   Several threads can belong to a single
>   application domain, and while a given
>   thread is not confined to a single
>   application domain, at any given time,
>   a thread executes in a single
>   application domain.

In your example, you create threads (or more specifically the thread pool does so) and thus the code will run on these threads. However, I am not sure I would recommend creating AppDomains on thread pool threads like that.

Unloading an AppDomain will abort any threads in the AppDomain. I honestly don't know how the thread pool will react to this. More info about unloading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unload.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

An App Domain is something larger than a thread, but smaller than a process.  You could think of them as potentially collections of several threads.  If an App Domain creates another, new App Domain, the new App Domain will have it's own thread.  A thread in one App Domain will never also be part of another App domain, nor will it be allowed to talk directly to threads from other App Domains.

Comment: _" If an App Domain creates another, new App Domain, the new App Domain will have it's own thread."_. While I'm not the downvoter, that statement is a little besides what's actually happening. When you create another AppDomain, it will execute in the current thread. You will have to create a new thread specifically and create and start the new AppDomain in that thread, if you want to run the AppDomain in its own thread.

Comment: I do use app domains to isolate plugins, and the behavior i see is the one described by @abel